# Tkinter GUI – How to remove a row of Entry widgets, using a Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a table, using `ttk.Entry` and `ttk.Combobox' ( rows and columns – amount of rows can vary).

User should be able to delete an entire row of that table using a “Delete Button” placed on GUI.

1. Line to be deleted can be placed anywhere ( first, last, anywhere in between).
2. Without adding “checkbox” widget at the end/beginning of each line to flag the desired line.

Tried:

a) Using `focus_get()` to determine Entry’s row number, and then to delete entire row of widgets. **But**, when pressing “Delete Button” `focus_get()` changes from Entry’s to Button’s and “Delete Button” got deleted.

b) I haven't tried, but there is a way using class bind to entire, but it seems not elegant.

Any ideas what is the “right” way to so that?

Edit 1: Adding pic of [image: GUI]. Selecting any Entry, would delete entire row of widgets

Comment: Keep in a variable the last selected row. Delete it when you press the button. What part is hard?

Comment: @stark to `bind` each and every widget ? it hope there is a better way

Comment: Set the variable in the validate method.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve]. I assume you're using ttk buttons but you don't explicitly state that.

Comment: You could have each row created in its own frame and then have a `x` button next to the row that can be used to `destroy()` the frame.

Comment: @Mike-SMT if you meant by x button what I wrote on 2. - it would be too crowded at GUI

Comment: If you are concerned about it being crowded then I would suggest writing up your rows to be inside of a list. This way you should be able to use your current delete button to select the row you wish to remove by index of the list. It would still be a frame per row so you can perform `destroy()` on that index in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state it in your question, but I'm assuming you're using `ttk` for the buttons. The ttk button widget takes focus when you click on it, which is both different from tkinter, and different from how buttons should work in general. In my opinion this is a bug in the ttk button, but I raised the issue years ago and the developers decided to keep the behavior.

The quick fix is to set the `takefocus` option to False for the button. This has the unfortunately side effect of breaking the ability to traverse your gui with the keyboard (eg: press tab to give move focus from widget to widget). Both problems can be solved with some custom bindings.

Here is a program that illustrates the difference between setting `takefocus` to `False` and `True`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def click():
    label.configure(text="Widget with focus: %s" % root.focus_get())

e1 = ttk.Entry(root, name="e1")
e2 = ttk.Entry(root, name="e2")
label = ttk.Label(root)

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Steal focus", command=click, name="b1", takefocus=True)
b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Don't Steal focus", command=click, name="b2", takefocus=False)

e1.pack(fill="x")
e2.pack(fill="x")
label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
b1.pack(side="left")
b2.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bryan - Great example, "elegant" as I was looking for.

Comment: Since I didn't name each entry - any idea how can associate this number: .1976965872.1976966128.1976965936.1982974256.1976966224.1976966352.1977008240 - to entry line ?

Comment: @Guy.D: the name is irrelevant. It was just so the code could easily print something useful. The widget is the result of `root.focus_get()`.

Comment: that I know- still, I need to get row's number somehow in order to delete all widgets on that row

Comment: @Guy.D: if you're using `grid`, you can call `root.focus_get().grid_info()` which returns a dictionary of all of the grid parameters. Or, keep all of your entry widgets in a list of lists, then just search each sub-list to see which one has the entry widget. There are dozens of ways to solve this problem.

Comment: EXACTLY !!- I"ll post a complete answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan Oakley suggested, here is the relevant portion of updated code- as an answer to my question.

Button's focus was set to `False`

```
del_row_button = ttk.Button(buttons_frame, width=10, text="Delete Row", takefocus=False, command=self.del_row)
        del_row_button.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx= 5)
```

and `self.del_row_button` callback updated to delete the exact line in `self.datafile` by getting widget's row number using `grid_info().get('row')-1`

```
def del_row(self):

        #delete data from list
        del self.datafile[self.class_frame.focus_get().grid_info().get('row') -1]

        #save data
        self.save_data()

        #destroy and rebuild rows with updated data
        self.rows_frame.destroy()
        self.rebuild_table()

        print("row deleted")
```